# How to implement push notification service for a crossplatform webapp?

Tags: jquery, web-applications, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to integrate push notification with my web app built using HTML ,javascript and jquery mobile and packaged with phonegap for android.

Can anyone please suggest some links to go for that.

For android complete documentation is given on developers.android.com.

But for webapp I dont know how to proceed.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its very nice example for push notification: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

Comment: yes I did read about that ..
Is it for native application's only or can be integrated with webapp aswell

Comment: your question is about phonegap with push notification

Comment: It is for cordova(phonegap) not for native app.

Comment: ok i’ll check with that thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by others [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) seems good option as per your requirement. It can be implemented and free to use. You have to configure for different platforms. 
This plugin is for use with Cordova, and allows your application to receive push notifications on Amazon Fire OS, Android, iOS, Windows Phone and Windows8 devices.

- The Amazon Fire OS implementation uses Amazon's ADM(Amazon Device
  Messaging) service.
- The Android implementation uses Google's GCM (Google Cloud Messaging)
  service.
- The BlackBerry 10 version uses blackberry push service.
- The iOS version is based on Apple APNS Notifications.
- The WP8 implementation is based on MPNS.
- Windows8 uses Microsoft WNS Notifications.

For detailed implementation steps for above platforms you can check this [page](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push#installation)

### Hope this is helpful to you with your question..!

#### Edit

Links are updated with the latest Github Repos.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly connect to GCM or APNS with the [GenericPush plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) or connect using an intermediate 3rd party such as [UrbanAirship](http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/phonegap.html), PushWoosh ([iOS](http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/ios/ios-additional-platforms/push-notification-sdk-integration-for-phonegap/)/[Android](http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android/android-additional-platforms/phonegapcordova-sdk-integration/)) or [PlotProjects](http://www.plotprojects.com/phonegap-cordova-plugin/) (for location based push messages) who also provide additional services and tooling for sending push messages

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can do it using [UrbanAirship](http://urbanairship.com) service

Comment: I did check it but that is paid..

Comment: unfortunatly yes, but this is the best

Comment: As I was going through some links I came across pushPlugin for phone-gap you have any idea on that?

Comment: thanks anyways  Hazem :)